# Isabelle/HOL - Circuits

Tags: isabelle

I am trying to do this coursework, being stuck for days.

I have a data type circuit which is defined as

```
datatype "circuit" = 


 NOT "circuit"
| AND "circuit" "circuit"
| OR "circuit" "circuit"
| TRUE
| FALSE
| INPUT "int"
```

And a function that optimizes circuits by removing consecutive NOT gates, and another function that checks if a circuit has two consecutive NOT gates. I need to write a theorem that proves that once a function has been optimized, it does no longer contain two consecutive NOT gates. Here is what I have:

```
fun opt_NOT where
 "opt_NOT (NOT (NOT c)) = opt_NOT c"
| "opt_NOT (NOT c) = NOT (opt_NOT c)"
| "opt_NOT (AND c1 c2) = AND (opt_NOT c1) (opt_NOT c2)"
| "opt_NOT (OR c1 c2) = OR (opt_NOT c1) (opt_NOT c2)"
| "opt_NOT TRUE = TRUE"
| "opt_NOT FALSE = FALSE"
| "opt_NOT (INPUT i) = INPUT i"

fun check_NOT where
"check_NOT (NOT (NOT c) ) = True" 
| "check_NOT (NOT (AND c1 c2)) = check_NOT (AND c1 c2) "
|"check_NOT (NOT (OR c1 c2)) = check_NOT (OR c1 c2)"
| " check_NOT TRUE = False " 
| " check_NOT FALSE = False " 
| "check_NOT (NOT TRUE ) = False" 
|"check_NOT ( NOT FALSE ) = False" 
|"check_NOT (INPUT i) = False " 
|" check_NOT (NOT (INPUT i)) = False " 
| "check_NOT (AND c1 c2) = (if check_NOT c1 = True then True 
else if check_NOT c2 = True then True else False ) " 
| " check_NOT (OR c1 c2) = (if check_NOT c1 = True then True 
else if check_NOT c2 = True then True else False ) " 

theorem "check_NOT (opt_NOT c) = False " 
  apply(induct rule: opt_NOT.induct)
            apply auto
```

Now, after `apply auto` the theorem is left with a single subgoal which is `check_NOT c = False`. I know that the proof should not even go this direction to have this as a subgoal. I have tried instantiating the `opt_NOT.induct` by using `opt_NOT.induct [of ]` with no success.

I also have a simulate function:

```
   fun simulate where
  "simulate (AND c1 c2) ρ = ((simulate c1 ρ) \<and> (simulate c2 ρ))"
| "simulate (OR c1 c2) ρ = ((simulate c1 ρ) \<or> (simulate c2 ρ))"
| "simulate (NOT c) ρ = (\<not> (simulate c ρ))"
| "simulate TRUE ρ = True"
| "simulate FALSE ρ = False"
| "simulate (INPUT i) ρ = ρ i"
```